# Can GAN's be used to fill in gaps?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, gan

Is it possible to make a Generative Adversarial Network that, given a fragment of a valid piece of data, can identify the patterns involved and generate something close to the original piece of data? From what I understand, typical GANs' generators take in a noise vector and output the generated data, but would training a GAN generator with fragmented data as input and complete data as the label? And would there be problems with training the discriminator using the same dataset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This task (filling in the rest of some data / image, given only part of it), is called inpainting. This can be done with conditional GANs.

In a conditional GAN, the generator is given both the noise vector $z$ and also the conditional input $x$ (the fragment of valid data), and is supposed to output a plausible reconstruction of the whole data. The discriminator GAN can also be conditioned on the available data $x$, and tries to judge if the reconstruction is real or fake.

[Free-Form Image Inpainting with Gated Convolution](https://arxiv.org/abs/1806.03589) is one example of using GANs for inpainting tasks. Note that in the case of inpainting tasks, it's typical not to train as a pure generator/discriminator, but also to provide additional supervision in the form of L2 loss or style loss, using the complete image/data as supervision.

Comment: Thanks this is exactly the answer I was searching for!